# Flutter web Dev with Firebase auth: MissingPluginException

Tags: android, ios, firebase, flutter, web

Im developing a Flutter web site with firebase auth.
i followed the documents on firebase.com, and when i run the project i get an error:

```
Overflow on channel: plugins.flutter.io/firebase_auth.  Messages on this channel are being discarded in FIFO fashion.  The engine may not be running or you need to adjust the buffer size if of the channel.
theres an error
MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method signInAnonymously on channel plugins.flutter.io/firebase_auth)
```

this is the flutter doctor:

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[√] Flutter (Channel beta, 1.20.0-7.3.pre, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18363.959], locale en-US)
[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.3)
[√] Chrome - develop for the web
[√] Android Studio (version 3.6)
[√] VS Code, 64-bit edition (version 1.47.3)
[√] Connected device (3 available)
• No issues found!
```

I added the relevant dependencies in the pubspec.yaml and added the relevant scripts in the index.html file and still get this error.

```
#firebase dependencies
firebase_core: ^0.4.0+9
firebase_auth: ^0.14.0+5
cloud_firestore: ^0.12.9+5
```

Comment: What does your pubspec look like?

Comment: please shared ```pubspec.yaml``` file

Comment: 'version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.7.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter


  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.3

  #firebase dependencies
  firebase_core: ^0.4.0+9
  firebase_auth: ^0.14.0+5
  cloud_firestore: ^0.12.9+5

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I copied the lib folder into a new flutter project and it fixed the problem.
Thanks for your help!